# Querying a collection in MongoDB; but needing to access a different property on the Schema Object

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Trying to figure out how to pull off this query in MongoDB:

CategorySchema

```
const CategorySchema = new Schema({
// Declare a unique name for each category.
  name: {
   required: true,
   type: String,
   unique: true
  },
// This is the object that contains the 3 responsive image collections.
 photos: {
   mobile: [],
   tablet: [],
   desktop: []
 }
});
```

addPhoto()

```
/**
* addPhoto(arg, arg2, arg3)
* - @param {String} name
* - @param {Object} image
* - @param {String} type
* - @return {Promise}
* - NOTE: Schema.statics allows for creating methods
* - on the Schema class.
*/
CategorySchema.statics.addPhoto = async function (name, image, type) {
  // Find category 'name' & push the imageUrl to the key 'photos' array.
  const list = await this.findOneAndUpdate({ name }, { $push: { photos: image.url } });
  // Return the updated category.
  return list;
  };
```

Initially `addPhoto()` worked fine before changing `photos` to an object containing the 3 arrays. Now I have `addPhoto` accepting a third argument `type` which will be one of the 3 keys in the `photos` object.

Problem I'm running into is how to pull of this query. I query the collection by name because that is unique to each collection. `photos` is present in each collection so I can't query that; but ultimately need to be able to access `photos[type]` to perform the `$push`. Any ideas on how I might be able to achieve that? I've been playing with a few different query operators but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update addPhoto function like

```
/**
* addPhoto(arg, arg2, arg3)
* - @param {Object} filter Eg {name: someName, type: someType}
* - @param {Object} image
* - @return {Promise}
* - NOTE: Schema.statics allows for creating methods
* - on the Schema class.
*/
CategorySchema.statics.addPhoto = async function (filter, image) {
  // Find category 'name' & push the imageUrl to the key 'photos' array.
  const list = await this.findOneAndUpdate(filter, { $push: { photos: image.url } });
  // Return the updated category.
  return list;
  };
```

from this you can add more filter in future